# Translate only specific section of a page

Tags: jquery, html, google-translate

Is there any way to translate any specific section of a page.

My code:

```
function googleTranslateElementInit() {

  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'af', }, 'google_translate_element');

}
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

I know we can use notranslate class if we don't want to translate a section of a page but i can't place it everywhere on my page.